# Node: child_process.spawn not working on Java even though it's in the path (ENOENT)

Tags: java, node.js

I was debugging WebDriverJs in Windows today, and ran into an error that I traced down to spawning Java:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('java');
```

The end error is as follows:

```
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

java.exe is in C:\Windows\System32\, and C:\Windows\System32 is in path (and the path in Node correctly includes it). Trying the full path to Java didn't seem to work either.

What's going on? `spawn('node')`, as a counter-example, doesn't fail. Java prints out something when I type it from the command line.

Comment: try the procedure at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-to-debug-any-node-js-child-process-error-spawn-enoent

Comment: I have the same problem. It used to work in node 0.10, it seems to fail with node 0.12. Which version of node are you using?